# Looping frames, and using keyboard listener to continue to next frames

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

Im still rather new to flash.
Im currently working on animation that I want to use to present my work with. I want to run short clip, consisting of 180 frames, that continually loops while I talk. Then when I press left key on the keyboard, the animation must continue.
I can get to loop the clip, using gotoAndPlay, but as soon as add the addEventListener. The I tried to incorporate a Boolean value, but that fails as well. Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as creating a **new symbol** that will contain your animation of 180+ frames. Inside this symbol/**movieclip** you can add code on frames which you need to loop **(F9)**. So on frame 180 you'd write `gotoAndPlay(1);`. And when you need to continue from the parent call `clip.gotoAndPlay(181);`